# Max from a column

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Activity

```
      Cursor mSent = myDBHlpr.getMostMessagesSent(getActivity());
    while (mSent.moveToNext()) {
        mMostMessagesSent.setText(mSent.getString(mSent.getColumnIndex("Name")));
    }
    mSent.close();
```

Helper

```
  public Cursor getMostMessagesSent(FragmentActivity usageSettings) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USER_DATA + " WHERE " + KEY_MESSAGES_SENT + "=(SELECT MAX(" + KEY_MESSAGES_SENT + ")" + " FROM " + TABLE_USER_DATA + ")", null);
    return cursor;
}
```

The data is not showing... im sure i have made some silly error but dont know where... can someone please help me out

Query

```
SELECT * FROM  UserData  WHERE MessagesSent=(SELECT MAX(MessagesSent) FROM  UserData);
```

Comment: Can you show your SQL query in normal form but not in code?

Comment: Look to the edit @KedarLimaye

Comment: Your post title does not match your post contents. How is the SQL `Max()` function involved in your problem?

Comment: What is data type of column 'messagesent' ?If possible show sample data of your table

Comment: String userQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USER_DATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_MESSAGES_SENT + " INTEGER, " + KEY_MESSAGES_RECIEVED + " INTEGER, "
                + KEY_MESSAGES + " INTEGER, " + KEY_TIME_SPENT + " TEXT)"; @KedarLimaye

Comment: Does this query SELECT MAX(MessagesSent) FROM  UserData produce any output?

Comment: How can i check that @KedarLimaye

Comment: @NikkiZepher - In your IDE for sqllite